# check if list ordered according to another list c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of strings, which is ordered with a particular method :

```
list1 : { "E", "C", "B", "A"};
```

Now I want to check other arrays that if it was ordered according to list1, then it is correct.

for example :

```
array: { "A", "C", "E", "B" } //false - not ordered according to list1
array: { "E", "B", "C" }      //false - not ordered according to list1
array: { "C", "A"}            //true-   ordered according to list1
```

Function codes:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string> { "E", "C", "B", "A"};

public static bool IsSorted(string[] array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
       if () //Your opinion
       {
       return false;
       }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: what is in `int[] array`?

Comment: should your `int[]` actually be `string[]` to match your reference array? If not I am very confused about what you are after...

Comment: @Chris It was my mistake. updated

Comment: can `list1` contain duplicates?

Comment: A simple algorithm assuming list1 only contains unique items would be to start with the first character of array and go through list1 until you find it. Once you have move onto the second character of array and keep moving through list1 til you find the next value. If you reach the end of array first then it is valid, if you reach the end of list1 first then it is not valid.

Comment: Must all the elements of the other list be present in `list1` for the result to be true?

Comment: @chris No, Is not duplicateds, No fast way with linq?

Comment: @Matthew Watson no , not necessary

Comment: @hiancuei Then you accepted an incorrect answer, because it returns false anytime the second sequence has an element not in the first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's easy using Lists instead of array

Here is an example :

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
  list1.Add(1);
  list1.Add(2);
  list1.Add(3);

List<int> list2 = new List<int>();

  list2.Add(2);
  list2.Add(3);


 Console.WriteLine( list1.Intersect(list2).SequenceEqual(list2)); // Will return true
```

Posted an example about int variables according to your example, You can use what ever type you want

**UPDATE** : It works well with arrays too ( Thanks to  @Matthew Watson)

```
int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] arr2 = { 2, 3 };
Console.WriteLine( arr1.Intersect(arr2).SequenceEqual(arr2)); // will return true
```

Comment: Didn't try it before with arrays. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: @kaj: All linq commands tend to work on `IEnumerable<T>` so it will work on virtually all generic "list like" objects.

Answer (score 1):

For the case `<=` (`{ "E", "E" }` is `true`) it is quite simple:

```
static List<string> list1 = new List<string> { "E", "C", "B", "A" };

// Uses a <= algorithm, so "E", "E" is true
public static bool IsSorted(IEnumerable<string> enu)
{
    // index of last letter used in list1
    int lastIndex = 0;

    foreach (string str in enu)
    {
        // Start searching from the last index found
        int index = list1.IndexOf(str, lastIndex);

        // index == -1 means not found
        if (index == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        lastIndex = index;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comments in code.

if you want a `<`, so that `{ "E", "E" }` is `false`:

```
// Uses a < algorithm, so "E", "E" is false
public static bool IsSorted(IEnumerable<string> enu)
{
    // Note that we have a +1 in the IndexOf to balance the -1 here
    int lastIndex = -1;

    foreach (string str in enu)
    {
        // Start searching from the last index found + 1
        int index = list1.IndexOf(str, lastIndex + 1);

        // index == -1 means not found
        if (index == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        lastIndex = index;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two LINQ methods for that: [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the items that are common to both lists; and then [SequenceEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal(v=vs.110).aspx) to check if both lists have the same items in the same order. So:

```
listToCheck.Intersect(list1).SequenceEqual(listToCheck)
```